# Difference between call-by value and call-by sharing

Tags: java, javascript

What is difference between call-by value and call-by sharing ?

I was reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) , it says JavaScript is call –by sharing ? 
If it is true then why Java is call-by value not call by sharing .

Comment: Who said it isn't? Did you read the Wikipedia article? It explains the difference. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Comment: That answer is completely wrong. There's no such thing as "call by sharing". All parameter passing in JavaScript is by value.  Object values are references in all cases, so object references are also passed by value. (*edit* - ok well I can't gainsay Barbara Liskov, but honestly nobody uses the term "call by sharing", at least not around me.)

Comment: You are referring to the question which states "they can be both passed-by-value " ?

Comment: In this C language tutorial we will take a look at call by value and call by reference (also known as pass-by-value and pass-by-reference). These methods are different ways of passing (or calling) data to functions. Check This http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference

Comment: Call by sharing is not really a common term and simply describes the practice to pass object references as values. It's still call by value.

Comment: So if I am passing reference  as a value it is call by sharing .

Comment: Forget that you ever heard the term "call by sharing". This is the first time I've *ever* heard it, and apparently it doesn't even have a clearly-defined meaning.

Comment: Yes. "Call by reference" means that a reference to the *variable's memory location* is passed. This allows the callee to change that variable. However, having an object reference only allows you to mutate the object, not the variable via which the object was passed. The object reference is the value of the variable.

Comment: *Call/pass-by-X* terminology is best avoided as a whole because there are so many subtle variations in each particular language that the terms lose any traction. And actually the "call-by-sharing" term is the most meaningful of them all because it talks about the *effects* rather than the *mechanics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia states

> the term "call by sharing" is not in common use; the terminology is inconsistent across different sources"

so while Java could be considered call by sharing it is not call this as the term doesn't have standard meaning.

Instead Java refers to "call by value" as the only variable types are primitives and references and these are always passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

The key distinction you must have in mind is, *what constitutes the value of an expression*. In

```
int i = 2+3;
```

the value of `i` is the number 5 itself. In

```
Date d = new Date();
```

the value of `d` is a *reference* to a Date object, not the object itself.

Once you have that cleared, Java is a strictly pass-by-value language. This means that the value of an expression is *copied* to a new location private to the called method. It can modify that location with no effect on the calling method.

However, in

```
Date d = new Date();
modify(d);
```

the object referred to by `d` is passed "by sharing": the called method gets a copy of the reference to the object, therefore it can modify the object in a way which the calling method will observe. What the called method *cannot* modify is the caller's reference to the object, so it cannot make the caller see another object when the method returns. Therefore

```
Date d = new Date();
Date d2 = d;
modify(d);
System.out.println(d2 == d);
```

is guaranteed to print `true` whatever `modify` does to its copy of the `d` reference, or to the object it refers to. (Remember that `==` only compares *values*).